# Multiple triggers in Aurelia

Tags: aurelia

I want to trigger two different methods in aurelia, what's the best way to achieve this?

```
<a click.trigger="toggleSize(size.parts)" click.delegate="refreshPanel()" click.trigger="viewUtility.closeStickyDropdown($event)">
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you trigger one function which invokes all three in the js component?

Comment: Yes, I did exactly that, was wondering if there was another way to achieve this. But now looking back I think that's the best solution.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What I would probably do is the following

**HTML**

```html
<a click.delegate="yourFunction($event, size.parts)">
```

**Javascript**

```js
yourFunction(event, parts) {
    this.toggleSize(size.parts);
    this.refreshPanel();
    this.viewUtility.closeStickyDropdown(event); //Depends on what viewUtility is.
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you do want to have multiple triggers, in declarative form:

```html
<a click.capture="calledFirst()"
  click.trigger="calledSecond()"
  click.delegate="calledThird()"></a>
```

But I don't know if you really need to mess your view up like that.

There is another approach:

```html
<a click.delegate="(first() || 1) && (second() || 1) && (third())"></a>
```

Notice the `|| 1`, it helps ensure the right hand side of `&&` always evaluated