# Aurelia: call multiple functions on click

Tags: aurelia

Is it possible to call multiple functions on click of an html element?

For example:
`<input type="text" click.delegate="myFunc1();myFunc2()" />`

Comment: I believe the easiest way is to call one method, that will trigger other methods

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple triggers in Aurelia](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37058964/multiple-triggers-in-aurelia)

Answer (score 0):

Simply write a wrapper function to call your functions. And call the parent function on button click.